# Parsing Terraform files with inner conditions

Tags: terraform, hashicorp-vault, hcl, hashicorp

I'm trying to parse and configure a Terraform HCL configuration, using a script.
So far I've been using a tool named "[hclq](https://github.com/mattolenik/hclq)" (Link to github page).

Unfortunately, while this tool is great. When I have a conditional statement, such as:

```
resource "vault_identity_group" "group_a" {
    count = terraform.workspace != "prod" ? 1 : 0
    ...
}
```

As documented by HashiCorp: [Conditional Expressions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/conditionals.html)

I tried encasing the condition as a literal:

```
count = ${terraform.workspace != "prod" ? 1 : 0}
```

But it seems that is no longer supported by Terraform.

Does anyone have any idea how can I get over this issue?

Thank you!

UPDATE: I've found an error in my literal, it should be encased in quotation marks:

```
count = "${terraform.workspace != var.prod ? 1 : 0}"
```

This way, the `hclq` tool can parse it as a string, I also had to switch the `"prod"` string with a variable, as the TF configuration does not support character escaping.

Comment: What's wrong with your first example? And what do you mean by "not supported"? IIRC you get a warning for HCL1 syntax but it should still be parsed okay. It's worth mentioning that HCL1 syntax requires quotes around that interpolation though.

Comment: You haven't shown what the error message is.

Comment: I think the crucial problem here is that `hclq` is for version 1 of HCL, while Terraform is based on version 2, and so `hclq` isn't a suitable tool for processing a Terraform configuration written for Terraform versions v0.12 or newer. I think you'll need to adopt a different strategy for whatever your underlying problem is.